# ASP.NET Master Page on file in folder(s)

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a small problem with an ASP page. I have a master file and it works great on all pages in the ROOT; however, if I create a folder (say: reports and folder insider there called userRpts) and add a page, the master doesn't apply.

So, I have a fodler structure like:

/reports/UserRpts/UserData.aspx

Master is set as: MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" in the <%@ Page %>

Yet it doesn't apply. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you get any error message/exception?

Comment: From the look of what you've written it should work; so there is something else wrong, so you should try to debug the issue: Try making an entirely new website containing only a MasterPage and then do the subfolder structure (basically, make a minimized version to test with) - then see if you get the same problem. If you do - include the code and structure here.

Comment: Not sure what I did, but it just started working. Thanks for the comment.